# ArcPy Lists, describe funtion, loop

Tags: arcpy

could someone please help with me with the following? Just need to get an idea of the flow of the code.

i) How do you use the ListFeatureClasses function to create a list of all the shapefiles. Loop through that list and use a copy tool to copy the datasets to another location. When this script is completed incorporates it as a script tool with parameters for the input and output workspaces?

ii) How do you modify the above script to incorporate an If statement. You only want to the first four shapefiles copied so once this amount of files has been copied use an if statement to halt to loop?

iii) How do you use the describe function and halt the execution of the program if an input layer is not of point geometry?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Please do not mistake us for a code writing service.  To get help with specific parts of your code you will need to research/ask about each separately, and present code snippets of what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This is unntested and incomplete, but should give you the gist of it. Plenty of ways to make this "more Pythonic", but hopefully you can understand this code. You will have to correctly set your `workspace`.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace('workspace') # ListFeatureClasses just works off this environment variable
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='Point') # optional, restrict to point FCs
for i, fc in enumerate(fcList):
    if i <= 4:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, "d:/base/output.gdb/feature_{}".format(i))
    else:
        pass
```